# Cannot figure out why query is failing

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying migrate over some code that inserts data into a database to work moving forward w postgres. The code/queries below are failing and after looking at the sizes of the arrays it seems as if it should be working.

Any input as to why this is failing would be fantastic.

Where my SQL looks like:

```
sql = "insert into postgres.options.options (delta,gamma,rho,theta,\"impVol\",value,vega,date,ticker,\"callPut\",\"Chg\",\"maturity\",\"Symbol\",\"Strike\",\"Implied\",\"Last\",\"Vol\",\"Ask\",\"Bid\") values " \
      "(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
```

And where my data looks like this:

```
data=[0.782154229511169, 0.026557152004256603, 0.005658995525391192, -0.4087164010990902, 136.71875, 8.94733166658628, 0.02387435675989819, 20150706, u'SVXY', u'C', -2.9, 20150710, u'SVXY150710C00070000', 70.0, 0.0, 7.9, 5.0, 9.2, 8.7]
```

And my python code reads as:

```
       cur.execute(sql,data)
        conn.commit()
```

And my create statement on the table reads as:

```
CREATE TABLE options.options
(
  delta double precision,
  gamma double precision,
  rho double precision,
  theta double precision,
  "impVol" double precision,
  value double precision,
  vega double precision,
  _id text,
  date bigint,
  ticker text,
  "callPut" text,
  "Chg" double precision,
  maturity integer,
  "Symbol" text,
  "Strike" double precision,
  "Implied" double precision,
  "Last" double precision,
  "Vol" double precision,
  "Ask" double precision,
  "Bid" double precision
)
```

And my error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jasonmellone/PycharmProjects/price_options_multithread/migrate_error_options.py", line 41, in <module>
    cur.execute(sql,data)
InternalError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a error in your insert statement. `postgres.options.options` is not a valid table because PostgreSql thinks, you mean a reference to another database. Change this:

```
insert into postgres.options.options...
```

to this:

```
insert into options.options...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have created a table `options` in `options` schema. Whereas you are inserting with `postgres` schema.

Change your insert:

```
sql = "insert into options.options  ..."
```

Answer (score 0):

Building my query string in python, and by using SQLAlchemy I was able to insert using the following logic:

```
def get_engine():
    engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://user:password@localhost/postgres')
    return engine

db = get_engine()
connection = db.connect()
connection.execute(sql)
```